# Adding dots to int in dart

Tags: dart, number-formatting

I have a number like `197695863` and I want to convert it to human readable format such as `197.695.863` in Dart. I could not find a way to do this converting process. Anyone know that how to achieve this formatting?

Comment: Try usng the [`NumberFormat` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) from [`package:intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

Comment: Thanks! I did it with NumberFormat from intl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  final f = NumberFormat("###,###.###", "tr_TR");
  f.format(d.truncate());
```

This piece of code might solve the problem.